# Microk8s - Non-HA single node, leaving node removes all pods

Tags: kubernetes, data-recovery, microk8s

Iam running the microk8s in ubuntu in no high availability i.e. there is a single node onto the same machine where it is installed. I updated the certificates and then i issue following command:

```
sudo microk8s leave
```

as it was advised that after upgrading the certificates nodes have to leave and rejoin.

It give following messages:

```
Generating new cluster certificates.
Waiting for node to start.
```

and then i stopped microk8s and then started again, the node appeared however all of my pods / namespaces are gone, how to recover?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same situation and the following solution worked for me:-

1. Check the /snap/microk8s directory - `ls -lart /snap/microk8s`
2. There must be more than one directory with a numerical name like `6236` etc which is the microk8s process pid.
3. The result of the command `ls -lart /snap/microk8s` must show a symlink pointing to one of these directories.
4. Stop the microk8s instance using `microk8s stop` and remove the `current` symlink.
5. Create a new symlink to the other directory using `cd /snap/microk8s && ln -s <other-dir-name> current`

This should restore the original cluster given that it's data is still available in the `/snap/microk8s/common` directory.